# When does it make sense, if ever, to remove the intercept from a logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, intercept

I normally work with linear regression, but came across a need to use logistic regression. I started with `glm(y ~ x1 + ..., data, family = binomial())`. Almost none of my variables were showing large coefs, which is fine.

Just for kicks I ran the same model, but excluded the intercept `glm(y ~ x1 + ... - 1, data, family = binomial())`. In this model most of the coefs were large and significant.

My problem is that I don't have too much experience with logistic regression and I am afraid of using this model simply because I don't want to mess up the interpretation. So my question is:

1. What is the interpretation of the exponentiated coefficients of a logistic regression model that has no intercept?

Comment: The proposed duplicate should address your questions 2 and 3. Regarding 1: the interpretation of (exponentiated) coefficients in logistic regressions per log odds is *per coefficient*, holding all other predictors constant. So this interpretation works in the exact same way with or without an intercept. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Your interpretation of the (log) odds ratio without an intercept is not what I think of. If it is, it must be a biased estimator because omitting an intercept "torques" the trend-line either up or down (resulting in a flatter or steeper probability curve). Yet my gut says there must be another interpretation: I believe it estimates *something* (else) consistently... if the OP edited the question to focus on item 1, I think it would be worth leaving open.

Comment: @AdamO, what do you have in mind? Certainly the exponentiated coefficients are odds ratios whether the intercept is there or not. Are you thinking of suppressing the intercept w/ only categorical variables (as in: [How can logistic regression have a factorial predictor and no intercept?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/130643/7290))?